# Modern webparts & iframes not navigating to a new page

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, office-365, iframe, web-partmodern-w

I am using SP classic site with using modern webparts in iframes. I have added the webpart into a site page and embedding this onto the homepage classic site. However, when  opening a link i.e a powerapp or powerbi report it only opens the powerapp inside the quick links on the homepage and does not open into a link, navigating to the site page (as it should be doing).

I have gone to the site page and tested the quick links, and they open into a new page successfully. Its just the SP Classic site & iframe that opens into the same SP page.

See screen shot. How do I change the behaviour?

[image]
[image]

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width: 400px;">
<iframe scrolling="no" src="https://bp365.sharepoint.com/sites/COP/SitePages/Quick-Links.aspx?web=1" scrollbars=false" style="border: 0px none; width: 450px; height: 552px; ">
</iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce it. And I check the links in the classic page with F12, the target attribute of  link is “_blank” and it opens the link in a new window/tab.

[image]

You can check your links with F12. Check if there is any code to change the target attribute.

You can use script to force links from iframe to be opened in new window.

For example: `$('a').attr('target','_blank');`

Here are several methods in the thread below:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037839/how-to-force-link-from-iframe-to-be-opened-in-the-parent-window